# Add Event listener is not working in js inside wordpress theme environement

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to add `addEventListener` in one of the `span` tag inside my header.php file but its not working I don't know why. I tried several times. I am working on wordpress theme. I am successfully imported the file. when i put `alert('helllo word)` outside addEvent listener it works but inside the addEvent listener nothing is working. Please help.

This is my code
header.php

```
 <div class="header__menu">
    
<span class="header__menu_btn">
<svg class="header__menu_icon" width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-filter-left" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 10.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
</svg>
</span>
<!-- <svg width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-x" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
</svg> -->
</div>
</nav>
</header>
<div class="header__sidenav">
    <div class="header__sidenav_content">
        <h1 >Hello From Drawer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

> header.js

```
const headerMenuIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("header__menu_btn");
const headerSideBar = document.querySelector("header__sidenav");

headerMenuIcon.addEventListener("click", function () {
  headerSideBar.style.width = "100%";
  alert("Hello world");
});
```

Comment: add  `defer` to your script tag: `<script defer src="..."></script>`

Comment: i am using wordpress environment Here its is imported like this  `    wp_enqueue_script('aditya', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/header.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
 `

Comment: Add one more argument `true` to ensure the script is added just prior to the closing `body` tag: `wp_enqueue_script('aditya', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/header.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true, true);`

Comment: still not working